# How to stop source blocks when rackSystem if full

Tags: anylogic

i saw a previous question about something like my issue but i couldn't make it work as suggested in the answer.

I have 5 sources that generate 5 different agents to be stored via a rackStore block in a rackSystem; a resource from a resource pool pick them up (rackPick block) and give them to an assembler. At some point i seize the same resource to do other tasks but the simulation is interrupted when the rack is full. I tried to make the sources stop when the rack is full in this way:

if( rackSystem.isFree(1, 1, 1) == false)
self.set_rate(0);

I typed this code in each source "on exit" bar but it doesn't work; what am i missing?

The rackSystem is made of 5 different palletRack blocks, each with 1 row/position/level.

Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

You are only checking if the position (0,0,0) is free. Instead, amend your condition to this:

```
if( rackSystem.hasSpace() == false) self.set_rate(0);
```

Comment: Thanks, i get what you mean, unfortunately it doesn't seem to work; my guess is that i type the condition in the wrong places; i tried typing that in every source block "on exit" or "on before arrival" but i keep getting the same error message:

"Exception during discrete event execution
root.rackStoreX
There are no empty cells in storage palletRackX"

Where "X" is 1, 2 , 3 , 4 or 5 depending on what palletRack is occupied

Comment: That is a structural problem. You have to ensure that your process chart is set so that  no agent ever is trying to get stored when there is no space. You could have a queue after your source (and remove the code above from the source) and give it infinite capacity. Then, have a hold block next to it that only lets through agents if the RackSystem has a free spot. Also, once an agent leaves the racksystem, it tells the hold block to let one more agent through. But you need to account for any agents between the hold block and the rack system, in your case all those currently being stored.

Comment: All right, i did what you suggested creating a conditional hold block typing "rackSystem.hasSpace() == false;" as the blocking condition;
 it all works fine until it has to let in the new agents, at that point it fails to let them in. I assume that happens because i'm not giving the hold blocks any signal to start letting the agents back through. How can i give such signal? I tried with the "unblock()" function (as explained in the AnyLogicHelp) but as i type that into the blocking condition bar i get an error in the console.

Comment: Can you please turn this into a new issue and describe it from scratch (ideally with Screenshots) so others can benefit from it as well 